# Portfolio Optimisation under weight constraints

Tags: r, optimization, portfolio, quadprog

With a lot of help from contributors to StackOverflow I have managed to put together a function to derive the weights of a 2-asset portfolio which maximises the Sharpe ratio. No short sales are allowed and the sum of weights add to 1. What I would like to do now is to constrain asset A to not being more or less than 10% from a user defined weight. As an example  I would like to constrain the weight of asset A to be no less than 54% or more than 66% (i.e 60% +/- 10%). So on the below example I would end up with weights of (0.54,0.66) instead of the unsconstrained (0.243,0.7570) .I assume this can be done by tweaking bVect but I am not so sure how to go about it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
asset_A <- c(0.034320510,-0.001209628,0.031900161,0.023163947,-0.001872938,-0.010322489,0.006090395,-0.003270854,0.017778990,0.017204915) 

asset_B <- c(0.047103261,0.055175057,0.021019816,0.020602347,0.007281368,-0.006547404,0.019155238,0.005494798,0.025429958,0.014929124)

     require(quadprog)

     HR_solve   <- function(asset_A,asset_B) {
     vol_A    <-  sd(asset_A)
     vol_B   <-  sd(asset_B)
     cor_AB  <-   cor(cbind(asset_A,asset_B),method="pearson")
     ret_A_B      <- as.matrix(c(mean(asset_A),mean(asset_B)))

      vol_AB <- c(vol_A,vol_B)
      covmat <- diag(as.vector(vol_AB))%*%cor_AB%*%diag(as.vector(vol_AB))

      aMat <- cbind(rep(1,nrow(covmat)),diag(1,nrow(covmat)))
      bVec  <- c(1,0,0)
      zeros <- array(0, dim = c(nrow(covmat),1))
      minw <-  solve.QP(covmat, zeros, aMat, bVec, meq = 1 ,factorized = FALSE)$solution
      rp <- as.numeric(t(minw) %*% ret_A_B)
      sp <- sqrt(t(minw) %*% covmat %*% minw)
      wp <- t(matrix(minw))

      sret <- sort(seq(t(minw) %*% ret_A_B,max(ret_A_B),length.out=100))
      aMatt <- cbind(ret_A_B,aMat)

      for (ri in sret[-1]){
      bVect  <- c(ri,bVec)
      result <-  tryCatch({solve.QP(covmat, zeros, aMatt, bVect, meq = 2,factorized = FALSE)},
                            warning = function(w){ return(NULL) } , error = function(w){ return(NULL)}, finally = {} )
     if (!is.null(result)){
     wp <-  rbind(wp,as.vector(result$solution))
     rp <-c(rp,t(as.vector(result$solution) %*% ret_A_B))
     sp <- c(sp,sqrt(t(as.vector(result$solution)) %*% covmat %*% as.vector(result$solution))) }

     }

      HR_weights <- wp[which.max(rp/sp),]
      as.matrix(HR_weights)
    }


HR_solve(asset_A,asset_B)


          [,1]
[1,] 0.2429662
[2,] 0.7570338
```

Comment: ok I have found how to do this.....

Comment: Have you checked `PortfolioAnalytics` package ?

Comment: Yes I have , but I would to be able to specify my own covariance matrix and risk extimates so quadprog works better for me....

Comment: FYI - PortfolioAnalytics uses `quadprog` under the hood anyway (together with couple of other solvers).

Comment: thank you I did not realise...

Comment: I have just looked at the package and you are right that you can specify the optimiser/solver ...but I can t see where you can enter your own covariance matrix.. it seems to calculate it from the data you enter, What I want to do is to be able to input my own definition of covmat  as in the above script. I want to test for various estimators so i would replace covmat by my own robust statistical measure..

Comment: You can do that as well. PortfolioAnalytics allows you to set portfolio moments using custom moment function (moment as in 'statistical moments'), so you can define portfolio and tell it to use your own (robust) covariance estimate, so you'd run `optimize.portfolio(returns, portfolio, optimize_method="quadprog", momentFUN="myCustomRobustFunction"` with `myCustomRobustFunction` returning a list with a `sigma`.See e.g. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PortfolioAnalytics/vignettes/custom_moments_objectives.pdf

Comment: That's great thank you so much, it is really helpful to me.I am a bit of a newbies to R so apologies if the question was somehow trivial...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should take a look at the link below.

http://economistatlarge.com/portfolio-theory/r-optimized-portfolio/r-code-graph-efficient-frontier

I think you'll learn a lot from that.  I'll post the code here, in case the link gets shut down sometime in the future.

```
# Economist at Large
# Modern Portfolio Theory
# Use solve.QP to solve for efficient frontier
# Last Edited 5/3/13

# This file uses the solve.QP function in the quadprog package to solve for the
# efficient frontier.
# Since the efficient frontier is a parabolic function, we can find the solution
# that minimizes portfolio variance and then vary the risk premium to find
# points along the efficient frontier. Then simply find the portfolio with the
# largest Sharpe ratio (expected return / sd) to identify the most
# efficient portfolio

library(stockPortfolio) # Base package for retrieving returns
library(ggplot2) # Used to graph efficient frontier
library(reshape2) # Used to melt the data
library(quadprog) #Needed for solve.QP

# Create the portfolio using ETFs, incl. hypothetical non-efficient allocation
stocks <- c(
 "VTSMX" = .0,
 "SPY" = .20,
 "EFA" = .10,
 "IWM" = .10,
 "VWO" = .30,
 "LQD" = .20,
 "HYG" = .10)

# Retrieve returns, from earliest start date possible (where all stocks have
# data) through most recent date
returns <- getReturns(names(stocks[-1]), freq="week") #Currently, drop index

#### Efficient Frontier function ####
eff.frontier <- function (returns, short="no", max.allocation=NULL,
 risk.premium.up=.5, risk.increment=.005){
 # return argument should be a m x n matrix with one column per security
 # short argument is whether short-selling is allowed; default is no (short
 # selling prohibited)max.allocation is the maximum % allowed for any one
 # security (reduces concentration) risk.premium.up is the upper limit of the
 # risk premium modeled (see for loop below) and risk.increment is the
 # increment (by) value used in the for loop

 covariance <- cov(returns)
 print(covariance)
 n <- ncol(covariance)

 # Create initial Amat and bvec assuming only equality constraint
 # (short-selling is allowed, no allocation constraints)
 Amat <- matrix (1, nrow=n)
 bvec <- 1
 meq <- 1

 # Then modify the Amat and bvec if short-selling is prohibited
 if(short=="no"){
 Amat <- cbind(1, diag(n))
 bvec <- c(bvec, rep(0, n))
 }

 # And modify Amat and bvec if a max allocation (concentration) is specified
 if(!is.null(max.allocation)){
 if(max.allocation > 1 | max.allocation <0){
 stop("max.allocation must be greater than 0 and less than 1")
 }
 if(max.allocation * n < 1){
 stop("Need to set max.allocation higher; not enough assets to add to 1")
 }
 Amat <- cbind(Amat, -diag(n))
 bvec <- c(bvec, rep(-max.allocation, n))
 }

 # Calculate the number of loops
 loops <- risk.premium.up / risk.increment + 1
 loop <- 1

 # Initialize a matrix to contain allocation and statistics
 # This is not necessary, but speeds up processing and uses less memory
 eff <- matrix(nrow=loops, ncol=n+3)
 # Now I need to give the matrix column names
 colnames(eff) <- c(colnames(returns), "Std.Dev", "Exp.Return", "sharpe")

 # Loop through the quadratic program solver
 for (i in seq(from=0, to=risk.premium.up, by=risk.increment)){
 dvec <- colMeans(returns) * i # This moves the solution along the EF
 sol <- solve.QP(covariance, dvec=dvec, Amat=Amat, bvec=bvec, meq=meq)
 eff[loop,"Std.Dev"] <- sqrt(sum(sol$solution*colSums((covariance*sol$solution))))
 eff[loop,"Exp.Return"] <- as.numeric(sol$solution %*% colMeans(returns))
 eff[loop,"sharpe"] <- eff[loop,"Exp.Return"] / eff[loop,"Std.Dev"]
 eff[loop,1:n] <- sol$solution
 loop <- loop+1
 }

 return(as.data.frame(eff))
}

# Run the eff.frontier function based on no short and 50% alloc. restrictions
eff <- eff.frontier(returns=returns$R, short="no", max.allocation=.50,
 risk.premium.up=1, risk.increment=.001)

# Find the optimal portfolio
eff.optimal.point <- eff[eff$sharpe==max(eff$sharpe),]

# graph efficient frontier
# Start with color scheme
ealred <- "#7D110C"
ealtan <- "#CDC4B6"
eallighttan <- "#F7F6F0"
ealdark <- "#423C30"

ggplot(eff, aes(x=Std.Dev, y=Exp.Return)) + geom_point(alpha=.1, color=ealdark) +
 geom_point(data=eff.optimal.point, aes(x=Std.Dev, y=Exp.Return, label=sharpe),
 color=ealred, size=5) +
 annotate(geom="text", x=eff.optimal.point$Std.Dev,
 y=eff.optimal.point$Exp.Return,
 label=paste("Risk: ",
 round(eff.optimal.point$Std.Dev*100, digits=3),"\nReturn: ",
 round(eff.optimal.point$Exp.Return*100, digits=4),"%\nSharpe: ",
 round(eff.optimal.point$sharpe*100, digits=2), "%", sep=""),
 hjust=0, vjust=1.2) +
 ggtitle("Efficient Frontier\nand Optimal Portfolio") +
 labs(x="Risk (standard deviation of portfolio)", y="Return") +
 theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill=eallighttan),
 text=element_text(color=ealdark),
 plot.title=element_text(size=24, color=ealred))
ggsave("Efficient Frontier.png")
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have found a way to do this... if you think there is a more elegant way please let me know...

```
 require(quadprog)

 HR_solve   <- function(asset_A,asset_B,mean_A,range_A) {
 vol_A    <-  sd(asset_A)
 vol_B   <-  sd(asset_B)
 cor_AB  <-   cor(cbind(asset_A,asset_B),method="pearson")
 ret_A_B      <- as.matrix(c(mean(asset_A),mean(asset_B)))

 vol_AB <- c(vol_A,vol_B)
 covmat <- diag(as.vector(vol_AB))%*%cor_AB%*%diag(as.vector(vol_AB))
 bVec  <-  c(1,0,0)

aMat <- cbind(rep(1,nrow(covmat)),diag(1,nrow(covmat)))

zeros <- array(0, dim = c(nrow(covmat),1))
minw <-  solve.QP(covmat, zeros, aMat, bVec, meq = 1 ,factorized = FALSE)$solution
rp <- as.numeric(t(minw) %*% ret_A_B)
sp <- sqrt(t(minw) %*% covmat %*% minw)
wp <- t(matrix(minw))

sret <- sort(seq(t(minw) %*% ret_A_B,max(ret_A_B),length.out=1000))

min_A <- mean_A * (1-range_A)
max_A <- mean_A * (1+range_A)

aMatt <- cbind(ret_A_B,aMat,-diag(2))
bVec  <- c(1,min_A,0,-max_A,-1)




for (ri in sret[-1]){
bVect  <- c(ri,bVec)


result <-  tryCatch({solve.QP(covmat, zeros, aMatt, bVect, meq = 2,factorized = FALSE)},
                        warning = function(w){ return(NULL) } , error = function(w){ return(NULL)}, finally = {} )
if (!is.null(result)){
wp <-  rbind(wp,as.vector(result$solution))
rp <-c(rp,t(as.vector(result$solution) %*% ret_A_B))
sp <- c(sp,sqrt(t(as.vector(result$solution)) %*% covmat %*% as.vector(result$solution))) }
}

HR_weights <- wp[which.max(rp/sp),]
as.matrix(HR_weights)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change aMat and bVec:

```
# sset A to be no less than 54% or more than 66%
  aMat <- cbind(rep(1,nrow(covmat)),diag(1,nrow(covmat)),c(1,0),c(-1,0))
  bVec  <- c(1,0,0,.54,-.66)
```